# Running python script with C#

Tags: c#, python

I have written the following code and I am getting no module named `fcntl` when i am running the python script using C#

```
print "hi how are you"
import nltk
a="hi how are you"
tokens=nltk.word_tokenize(a)
print tokens
```

Comment: [fcntl](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html) is only available on unix.  Are you developing on Windows?  If so, how did you get `fcntl`?  Maybe try to re-install using their instructions [here](http://www.nltk.org/install.html#windows)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly NLTK depends on subprocess module, which is not supported in embedded IronPython. There're already some answers on the subject:

- ["No module named fcntl" when py script run from c# but works from windows command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027157/no-module-named-fcntl-when-py-script-run-from-c-sharp-but-works-from-windows-c)
- [No module named fcntl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543229/no-module-named-fcntl)

### sys.path

Also check your `sys.path`. Probably it is not set automatically for embedded engine. You can set library paths like this:

```
engine.SetSearchPaths(
    new string[]
    {
        "C:\\Program Files\\IronPython 2.7",
        "C:\\Program Files\\IronPython 2.7\\Lib",
        "C:\\Program Files\\IronPython 2.7\\Lib\\site-packages",
    }
);
```

### sys.platform

Any module, dependent on `fcntl`, decides to import it only if `sys.platform == 'posix'`. Debug it's actual value inside your python code and try to force it to `"win32"` (before any other imports)

```
import sys
sys.platform = "win32"
```